# How can I improve on this login/session code?

Tags: php, security, session, authentication

I have been following [a tutorial on how to create a login system with a session](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html) so that pages cant be accessed unless a session has been created. At the moment its very simple and not secure.

QUESTION: How can I improve on this code (bellow) to make the sessions more secure? If you know of a tutorial regarding secure sessions for logins that I could follow please post a link! Thanks.

CODE:

checkLogin.php:

```
<!--Include Database connections info-->
<?php include('config.php'); ?>

<?php
    // username and password sent from form 
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];   
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql="SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1) {

        session_start();
        session_register("myusername");
        session_register("mypassword"); 
        header("location:login_success.php?");
        exit;
    }

    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
?>
```

login_success.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        header("location:main_login.html");
        exit;
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        header("location:index.php");
        exit;
    }   
?>
```

Comment: I would add `exit;` after the `header("location:login_success.php?");` line to exit the script and further executions

Comment: I would not use `mysql_*` functions. `:P`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

    $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];   
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "DataBase");

    // Check Connection
    if (!mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("Connect failed");
        exit();
    }

    // Move to MySQL(i) as MySQL is now obslete and use Prepare statment for protecting against SQL Injection in better and easier way
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= ? and password= ?');

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $myusername, $mypassword);
    //ss means expecting a variable of type string

    $stmt->execute();

    $count=mysqli_stmt::$num_rows($stmt);

    if($count>0) 
    {
        session_start();
        //Session Register is now history better go with
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
        header("location:index.php");
    }

    else 
    {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
?>
```

And instead of redirecting to **login_success.php** just redirect to **index.php**

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    header("location:main_login.html");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, im trying you suggestion now. When I run the code it gives this SQL error: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object, in regards to the line: $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= ? and password= ?');.

Comment: Sorry Corey! I was out last night. Well I have updated the code hope it solves your problem for more info on MySQL(i) refer to this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Thanks Abdul. Your link helped a lot, I was able to read and understand the code and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like session_register is deprecated and suggested registration of a session variable should be done through [php.net deprecated info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php):

```
$_SESSION["session_var_name"] = "value";
```

I don't think that it is good to store the actual password value in the session.  I can't think of a benefit for doing that.

All you need to do is store something in the session that the user has been successfully authenticated.

Below is an example of what code you can use below session_start()

```
$_SESSION['logged_in_user'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['logged_in_user_session'] = session_id();
```

Then following is example logic you can use to check if user is authenticated throughout your application.

```
session_start();

// verify login
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in_user']) && isset($_SESSION['logged_in_user_session'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['logged_in_user_session'] != session_id()) {
        // error: login
        header("Location: error_or_login_page.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```